# when click on button then show message

Tags: html, asp.net, css

i have a add admins account form and when i add account then i want to show message "successfully created" when i click on button  and here when i debug my project and open form then this label already shown how i remove this ..

[image]

here is css and html

```
<asp:Label ID="Lbe6" class="message success"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**css**

```
.message.success {
    border: 1px solid rgb(184, 201, 123);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(229, 237, 196), rgb(217, 228, 172)) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    color: rgb(63, 114, 39);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.message {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
```

code

```
protected void Btn_SignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                c1.SignUp(nametxt.Value, passtxt.Value, Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue),mailtxt.Value,numbtxt.Value);
                //GridView1.DataSource=ca.viewadmin();
                 Lbe6.Text = (" Account Successfully Created");
                //  GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch
            {

               lbe5.Text = ("SIGNUP FAILED.PLEASE TRY AGAIN");

            }
            nametxt.Value = "";
            passtxt.Value = "";

            mailtxt.Value = "";
            numbtxt.Value = "";

        }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 Lbe6.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Client Side msg or Server Side msg?

Comment: What are you trying to remove?

Comment: i try to remove this small object which is in pink color box and want to show this when i fill all textboxes and click on submit button then this will be show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void Btn_SignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//If not working properly set the visible attribute on button click also
            try
            {

                c1.SignUp(nametxt.Value, passtxt.Value, Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue),mailtxt.Value,numbtxt.Value);
                //GridView1.DataSource=ca.viewadmin();
                 Lbe6.Visible = true;
                 Lbe6.Text = (" Account Successfully Created");
                //  GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch
            {
               Lbe5.Visible = true;
               lbe5.Text = ("SIGNUP FAILED.PLEASE TRY AGAIN");

            }
            nametxt.Value = "";
            passtxt.Value = "";

            mailtxt.Value = "";
            numbtxt.Value = "";

        }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 Lbe6.Visible = false;
Lbe5.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
protected void Btn_SignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {  c1.SignUp(nametxt.Value, passtxt.Value, Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue),     
 Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue),m      ailtxt.Value,numbtxt.Value);
                //GridView1.DataSource=ca.viewadmin();
                 Lbe6.Text = (" Account Successfully Created");
                //  GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            catch
            {

               lbe5.Text = ("SIGNUP FAILED.PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
               lbe5.Visible = true;

            }
            nametxt.Value = "";
            passtxt.Value = "";

            mailtxt.Value = "";
            numbtxt.Value = "";

}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Lbe6.Visible = false;
     Lbe5.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: ok when i add this and then click on submit button then message not display...now what  i do?

Comment: @user3134694 on button click please add text and set visible to true. It will be visible for sure :)

Comment: @user3134694 can you please add your code of button click and what are you doing in code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the label until the message success is true then set your `Lbe6.Visible = false` and then set it back to `Lbe6.Visible = true` when you set your message success.